# How to specify polarplot radius range and make center non-zero

Tags: plotting

I have a dataset

```
data={{0,528.873644339619259370133231358},{\[Pi]/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{\[Pi]/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{\[Pi]/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{\[Pi]/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{\[Pi]/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{\[Pi]/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(7 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(2 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{\[Pi]/20,526.686527896233528640561700336},{\[Pi]/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(11 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{\[Pi]/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(13 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(7 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{\[Pi]/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(4 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(17 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{\[Pi]/10,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(19 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{\[Pi]/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(7 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(11 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(23 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(2 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(5 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(13 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(3 \[Pi])/20,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(7 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(29 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{\[Pi]/6,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(31 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(8 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(11 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(17 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(7 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{\[Pi]/5,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(37 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(19 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(13 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(2 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(41 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(7 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(43 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(11 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{\[Pi]/4,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(23 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(47 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(4 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(49 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(5 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(17 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(13 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(53 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(3 \[Pi])/10,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(11 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(14 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(19 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(29 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(59 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{\[Pi]/3,528.873644339619259370133231358},{(61 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(31 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(7 \[Pi])/20,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(16 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(13 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(11 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(67 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(17 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(23 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(7 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(71 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(2 \[Pi])/5,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(73 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(37 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(5 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(19 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(77 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(13 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(79 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(4 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(9 \[Pi])/20,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(41 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(83 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(7 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(17 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(43 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(29 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(22 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(89 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{\[Pi]/2,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(91 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(23 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(31 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(47 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(19 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(8 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(97 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(49 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(11 \[Pi])/20,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(5 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(101 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(17 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(103 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(26 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(7 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(53 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(107 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(3 \[Pi])/5,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(109 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(11 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(37 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(28 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(113 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(19 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(23 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(29 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(13 \[Pi])/20,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(59 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(119 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(2 \[Pi])/3,528.873644339619259370133231358},{(121 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(61 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(41 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(31 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(25 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(7 \[Pi])/10,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(127 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(32 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(43 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(13 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(131 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(11 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(133 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(67 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(3 \[Pi])/4,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(34 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(137 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(23 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(139 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(7 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(47 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(71 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(143 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(4 \[Pi])/5,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(29 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(73 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(49 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(37 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(149 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(5 \[Pi])/6,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(151 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(38 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(17 \[Pi])/20,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(77 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(31 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(13 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(157 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(79 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(53 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(8 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(161 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(9 \[Pi])/10,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(163 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(41 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(11 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(83 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(167 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(14 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(169 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(17 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(19 \[Pi])/20,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(43 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(173 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(29 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(35 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(44 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(59 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(89 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(179 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{\[Pi],528.873644339619259370133231358},{(181 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(91 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(61 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(46 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(37 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(31 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(187 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(47 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(21 \[Pi])/20,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(19 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(191 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(16 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(193 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(97 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(13 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(49 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(197 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(11 \[Pi])/10,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(199 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(10 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(67 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(101 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(203 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(17 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(41 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(103 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(23 \[Pi])/20,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(52 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(209 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(7 \[Pi])/6,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(211 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(53 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(71 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(107 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(43 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(6 \[Pi])/5,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(217 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(109 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(73 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(11 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(221 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(37 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(223 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(56 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(5 \[Pi])/4,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(113 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(227 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(19 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(229 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(23 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(77 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(58 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(233 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(13 \[Pi])/10,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(47 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(59 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(79 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(119 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(239 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(4 \[Pi])/3,528.873644339619259370133231358},{(241 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(121 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(27 \[Pi])/20,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(61 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(49 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(41 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(247 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(62 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(83 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(25 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(251 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(7 \[Pi])/5,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(253 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(127 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(17 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(64 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(257 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(43 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(259 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(13 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(29 \[Pi])/20,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(131 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(263 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(22 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(53 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(133 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(89 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(67 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(269 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(3 \[Pi])/2,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(271 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(68 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(91 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(137 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(55 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(23 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(277 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(139 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(31 \[Pi])/20,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(14 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(281 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(47 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(283 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(71 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(19 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(143 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(287 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(8 \[Pi])/5,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(289 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(29 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(97 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(73 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(293 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(49 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(59 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(74 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(33 \[Pi])/20,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(149 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(299 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(5 \[Pi])/3,528.873644339619259370133231358},{(301 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{(151 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(101 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(76 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(61 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(17 \[Pi])/10,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(307 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(77 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(103 \[Pi])/60,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(31 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(311 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(26 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(313 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(157 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(7 \[Pi])/4,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(79 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(317 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(53 \[Pi])/30,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(319 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(16 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(107 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(161 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(323 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(9 \[Pi])/5,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(65 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(163 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(109 \[Pi])/60,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(82 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(329 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(11 \[Pi])/6,518.426930690297148234885375271},{(331 \[Pi])/180,518.454982075280629999977683125},{(83 \[Pi])/45,518.538847139039640537879042252},{(37 \[Pi])/20,518.677660992956774285948063699},{(167 \[Pi])/90,518.869990112423973114627004133},{(67 \[Pi])/36,519.113844293100493008457792558},{(28 \[Pi])/15,519.406693428123590371660863735},{(337 \[Pi])/180,519.745489133714635072733099254},{(169 \[Pi])/90,520.126691243255141571954171468},{(113 \[Pi])/60,520.546299172024875284338160881},{(17 \[Pi])/9,520.999888125034160897771141773},{(341 \[Pi])/180,521.482650077935465582660650119},{(19 \[Pi])/10,521.989439405679829664884764547},{(343 \[Pi])/180,522.514822965880355129979584035},{(86 \[Pi])/45,523.053134364946115075776826460},{(23 \[Pi])/12,523.598532046840714158202586242},{(173 \[Pi])/90,524.145060749347051943096742738},{(347 \[Pi])/180,524.686715774122174551825003506},{(29 \[Pi])/15,525.217509418229425114996256715},{(349 \[Pi])/180,525.731538820215810494880926620},{(35 \[Pi])/18,526.223054387322239188038039672},{(39 \[Pi])/20,526.686527896233528640561700336},{(88 \[Pi])/45,527.116719301854351730155260080},{(353 \[Pi])/180,527.508741250496514921916790403},{(59 \[Pi])/30,527.858120278550272787517318897},{(71 \[Pi])/36,528.160853687393775035102270508},{(89 \[Pi])/45,528.413461121275069199295401496},{(119 \[Pi])/60,528.613029937485429372849525887},{(179 \[Pi])/90,528.757253546584900225040679099},{(359 \[Pi])/180,528.844462012942789685768979209},{2 \[Pi],528.873644339619259370133231358}}
```

Using ListPolarPlot,

```
ListPolarPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle ->Orange, AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(res\)]\)(Oe)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \(res\)]\)(Oe)"}, PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 600}]
```

I got the plot like this:

[image]

But I wish to get the plot like this, How to make it?  I need the radial axis starting from non-zero so one can see the six-fold feature of the data.

[image]

Comment: `ListPolarPlot[data, Joined -> True, PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> True]`.

Comment: The gridline is not what I want. I need the radial axis starting from non-zero so one can see the six-fold feature of the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** added missing grid line

```
ListPolarPlot[
 {# - {0, 517} & /@ data},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Orange,
 PolarAxes -> True,
 PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 330, 30] Degree,
   Table[{r, r + 517}, {r, 1, 12, 2}]},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 345, 15] Degree,
   Range[1, 12]}]
```

[image]